# Flutter account deletion

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing an application and in my application I want people to delete their account whenever they want. But in the code I wrote, their accounts are deleted, but their posts are stopped. How can I delete your posts at the same time?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73rD2.png)

```
onPressed: () async {

                bool step1 = true;
                bool step2 = false;
                bool step3 = false;
                bool step4 = false;
                bool step5 = false;
                while (true) {



                  if (step1) {
                    var delete = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                        .delete();
                    step1 = false;
                    step2 = true;
                  }



                  if (step2) {
                    //delete user info in the database
                    try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete();
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == 'requires-recent-login') {
                        print(
                            'The user must reauthenticate before this operation can be executed.');
                      }
                    }
                    step2 = false;
                    step3 = true;
                  }

                  if (step3) {
                    var docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('posts')
                        .doc('postId');

                    docUser.delete();

                    step3 = false;
                    step4 = true;

                  }
                  if (step4) {
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    step4 = false;
                    step5 = true;
                  }

                  if (step5) {
                    //go to sign up log in page
                    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                    step4 = false;
                  }

                  if (!step1 && !step2 && !step3 && !step4) {
                    break;
                  }
                }
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

Merhaba Tolunay, when I check your code I see you have this comment in your **step 2**;

> //delete user info in the database

But that action is done in **step 1**, stored into a variable and never used;

```
var delete = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('users')
         .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
         .delete();
```

Maybe an easier logic implementation will make the code more readable & structured and for this I have some suggestions;

1. First delete user data from Firestore Database since you will need the current user id to navigate through Collections/Documents with that user id.
2. Do not proceed with signOut method before deleting user from Firebase Auth, because currentUser will return null and you wont be able to delete your account.
3. During this process you can display a Loading widget so your user knows a process is ongoing.

```
    onPressed: () async {
              // It will await the completion of the Firestore data removal
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                  .delete();
    
              // Once data is removed from Firestore it will proceed to delete user
              try {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete();
              } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                if (e.code == 'requires-recent-login') {
                  print(
                      'The user must reauthenticate before this operation can be executed.');
                }
              }
            },
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. It just deleted the profile information.